# Append multiple types to the list

Tags: bash

What is my problem? I want to append extra types to the list but it only append the last how could I append multiple?

```
[ -f path/file1.txt ] && types+=( file1.txt )
[ -f path/file2.txt ] && types+=( file2.txt )

findArgs=( -false )
for type in "${types[@]}"; do
  findArgs+=(  -name '.upl' -o -name '.int' -o -name '.ini' -o -name '.htm' -o -name '.inc' -o -name '.css' -o -name '.example' -o -name '.cfg' -o -name '.cache' -o -name '.manifest' -o -name '.dsp' -o -name '.vdf' -o -name '.lst' -o -name '.gam' -o -name '.scr' -o -name '.nut' -o -name '.db' -o -name '.inf' -o -name '*.rc' -o -name "$type" )
done

find . '(' "${findArgs[@]}" ')' -printf '%P\0' |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the fixed types multiple times, once for each optional type. (As a result, you also end up missing some `-o` arguments.)

Instead, start by initializing `types` with the fixed types.

```
types=(
  '*.upl'
  '*.int'
  '*.ini'
  '*.htm'
  '*.inc'
  '*.css'
  '*.example'
  '*.cfg'
  '*.cache'
  '*.manifest'
  '*.dsp'
  '*.vdf'
  '*.lst'
  '*.gam'
  '*.scr'
  '*.nut'
  '*.db'
  '*.inf'
  '*.rc'
)
```

Then append the optional types as necessary:

```
[ -f path/file1.txt] && types+=(file1.txt)
[ -f path/file2.txt] && types+=(file2.txt)
```

*Then* build the `findArgs` array using `types`. That array will
then include all arguments for all types correctly.

```
findArgs=( -false )
for type in "${types[@]}"; do
  findArgs+=( -o -name "$type" )
done

find . '(' "${findArgs[@]}" ')' -printf '%P\0' | ...
```